# Stop deployment slot after X time - Azure YAML Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment-slots

To save memory in a development environment I would like to shutdown/stop a given deployment slot X time after a deployment has finished.

What is the best/easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Web jobs` to call the **Rest API** to `Stop` the deployment slot and `Start` the Deployment slot. But currently no options for to stop the slot for specific time.

Stops an app (or deployment slot, if specified).

`POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/slots/{slot}/stop?api-version=2021-02-01]`

Start an app (or deployment slot, if specified).

`POST` `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/slots/{slot}/start?api-version=2021-02-01`

Slot:

Name of the deployment slot. If a slot is not specified, the API will stop the production slot.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/start-slot)

Or you can use the pipeline to stop the slot [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet)

Comment: Thanks for your reply - too bad there is not an option to schedule this to eg. 2 hours after a swap