# Add start and stop task for staging slot in Azure deployment pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

- Add a task to all the deployment pipelines to first start the staging slot
- Add  task to all the deployment pipelines to stop the staging slot after the slot swap is successful

Tried this solution. ( [Stop deployment slot after X time - Azure YAML Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721848/stop-deployment-slot-after-x-time-azure-yaml-pipelines) ) but it's not picking up right slot.
Any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Add a task to all the deployment pipelines to first start the staging slot

In `Azure Devops`, open your Project and navigate to your pipeline.

- In your `Pipleline`, click on Edit.

[image]

- In the `Right pane`, Under `Tasks` option select `Azure App Service Manage`.

[image]

- Provide the `Subscription` and Authorize.
- Specify the `Action` as `Start App Service` and select your App Service.
- Select the Specify Slot option.
- Select the slot as Deployment.

[image]

- Add the task.

> - Add task to all the deployment pipelines to stop the staging slot after the slot swap is successful

- Add new task with `Stop App Service`.

[image]

References taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureAppServiceManageV0/README.md)